# How to overwrite a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function, pagespeed

I want to overwrite some functions because the function that I want to load first depends on user interaction (most of time) and I want to load first only an empty version of functions (to be sure that if this function is called, JavaScript will not stop the execution and throw an error). After the page loads, I want to load the actual function.

1. Is that a good idea?
2. Will the code below work on all browsers?

```
//for the first time
function name(){}
```

```
//after page loaded
function name(){....//long function//..........}
```

Comment: That sounds like typicall [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) imho...  **1.** `Is that good idea?` Probably not! **2.** `Sure, but why that?!`

Comment: @A.Wolff I edited a little bit

Comment: You can overwrite functions with new ones whenever your heart desires. If you need a filler to absorb calls for a limited amount of time, then do it.

Comment: Do you use `onclick` attribute for user interaction?

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent This is a good point. If OP is using obstrusive javascript, the solution would be to not use that but to bind events using unobstrusive methods, if possible...

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent yes some function is depend on click events when user click like button it call like functions and also execute another things

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is that good idea?

Probably not, but we'd have to know a great deal more about what you actually need to do; maybe for your use case, this is exactly the right solution.

Alternately, it might make more sense to provide some state information the (one) function can use to determine its logic.

> 2. does below code will work on all browsers?

Yes, and it's defined in the specification. If there are multiple function declarations in the same scope, the bottom one wins.

Alternately, you could assign to the identifier created by the first function declaration:

```
//for the first time
function name(){}
//when the page loads
name = function() { };
```

The advantage to doing this is that you can do it in a callback (for instance, an event handler), whereas (of course) writing a function declaration in an event handler only defines the function within that event handler's scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is helpful,I want to give example of usage logic:when page loaded posts will load via ajax request then  like.js will loaded which is contain all like functions,it is stable and can be bottom of page but there are some function depends on cases,for example create chat function - - - when user enter website notification scripts will loaded then will begin to execute itself,it will request to server and if server says that you have new message it will call create_chat function which is exactly really heavy and something I want to load after page loaded

Comment: - I define it earlier because I dont want to javascript to throw error

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it a good idea?

No.

> 2. Will it work in all browsers

Yes.

```
var func = function() {};

window.onload = function() {
    func = function() {
        ...new function definition...
    };
};
```

Use simple closure.

Comment: This is an answer without enough content, what are you even answering? :-)

Comment: I'm answering how to load a function when the whole page loads. Isn't that the question?

Comment: The OP's questions are, 1) Is it a good idea, and 2) is it browser compatible. The code in the question already handles the function overwrite.